# Why is re-assigning imported objects throw ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules, referenceerror

```
// fileA.js

export let dataObj = {name: "intitial name"};

export let changeDataObj = () => {
 dataObj = Object.assign({}, {
      name: "changed in changeDataObj fn"
 });
}
```

```
//fileB.js
import {dataObj, changeDataObj} from "./fileA.js";

const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
   const response = await myApiCall();
   console.log(dataObj); // {name: "initial name"}
   console.log(response); // {name: "name from api"}
   dataObj = Object.assign({}, response); 
   // Throws ReferenceError: dataObj not defined on my computer with Webpack, babel
    // throws Error: "dataObj" is read-only. in codesandbox.io vanilla template using parcel. Codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/nrn9o71jmm

   // but,
   changeDataObj();
   console.log(dataObj); // {name: "changed in changeDataObj fn"}
}
```

Why can't I re assign dataObj inside `myAsyncFunction` even though it is defined with `let` in different file but works if I call `changeDataObj` which is defined in the same file as `dataObj`. Is it the expected behavior or am I missing something ?

The link for codesandbox.io https://codesandbox.io/s/nrn9o71jmm

Please check the browser console instead of in-built codesandbox console to see errors.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async functions` but that the assignment target is from a module `import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I re assign dataObj inside `myAsyncFunction` even though it is defined with let in different file

The answer is in the other error message you are getting:

> "dataObj" is read-only

All imports are read-only. It doesn't matter how they are defined. The `ReferenceError` is likely due to how the code gets transformed.

> but works if I call `changeDataObj` which is defined in the same file as `dataObj`

Because `dataObj` is a normal `let` binding in that file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it a Webpack thing throwing `ReferenceError: dataObj is not defined` instead of saying `read-only` which seems correct from Parcel.

Answer (score 0):

If you just meant to have a local variable named `dataObj` (which may not be a good choice, but I'll assume so), then what you need is a `let` for your statement:

```
let dataObj = Object.assign({}, response);
```

Then the global `dataObj` is ignored and you get a new variable. I think that could be really confusing, though.

As Felix explains, all imports are marked as read-only and thus can't be assigned a new value. It's actually a great feature.